# How to specify childrens in anytree and print a tree

Tags: python

I am trying to print a tree using Wikipedia's sections but I am not able to figure out how to specify children node in anytree. Here is what I have tried so far,

```
import wikipediaapi
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, DoubleStyle
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
main_page = wiki_wiki.page('Stack_Overflow')
sections =  main_page.sections
print(RenderTree(sections))
```

but I am getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(RenderTree(sections))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/anytree/render.py", line 292, in __str__
    lines = ["%s%r" % (pre, node) for pre, _, node in self]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/anytree/render.py", line 292, in <listcomp>
    lines = ["%s%r" % (pre, node) for pre, _, node in self]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/anytree/render.py", line 272, in __next
    children = node.children
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'children'
```

I am expecting this output

```
1   History
1.1 Content criteria
1.2 User suspension
2   Statistics
3   Technology
4   Reception
5   See also
6   References
7   External links
```

I want it to go as deep as possible

Comment: always use the generic [python] tag for python questions. Use a version-specific tag if it is relevant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I only just started python, will keep in mind for future, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to double-check the [docs](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/api/anytree.render.html) and work through an example or two in the `anytree` class.  This class works with its self-defined tree structure, but `sections` is a straightforward list, not suitable to present to `RenderTree`.  I checked your interfacing with some simple `print` commands:

```
sections =  main_page.sections
print(type(sections), len(sections))
print("\n------------ sections -----------\n", sections)
render = RenderTree(sections)
print(type(render))
print("\n------------ final print -----------\n")
print(render)
print("\n------------ final print done -----------\n")
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'> 7

------------ sections -----------
 [Section: History (1):
The website was created
...
]
<class 'anytree.render.RenderTree'>

------------ final print -----------

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

Your list input does not have the `Node` structure that `anytree` expects.

Comment: thank you so much for your input, in that case anytree isn't a must for me, any other library would work I guess, but I am not sure which one, if you know how to print structure like required by me please share, I will keep looking at meantime

Comment: References to off-site resources is generally out of scope for Stack Overflow -- but I don't mind that you asked in the normal flow of the question.  *I* would handle this by writing my own parsing and extraction code, looking for the `Section:` header, the `level` that follows, and the very helpful `Subsections(n):` counter (`n` is the number of subsections at that level, which immediately follow).